# Firefox and System connects to novastor.com despite not being installed [W7]

Tags: windows-7, firefox, spyware

Okay this is weirdly creepy. This has been happening for a few months now.

[Novastor.com logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NjoaZ.png)

Resource monitor logs show my computer connecting to novastor.com despite currently not being installed. I searched my drives and apparently it was installed a long time ago (2014) and was removed.

My Firefox addons show nothing about novastor.com.

Is there malware or spyware in my computer or something?

Comment: does your installation of Everything(http://www.voidtools.com/) come from about the same time NovaBackup or another Novastor product was installed?

Comment: No I wasn't even using this computer when Novastor was installed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I finally figured it out:

It's because of the `etc/hosts` file. The very first entry is what Resource Monitor recognizes as the hostname:

```
127.0.0.1  novastor.com

# ...

127.0.0.1  localhost
```

Weird.